# Declaring vectors and pointers without creating any type objects

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, pointers, vector

Given the c++ class Student and the declarations for:

1. An array that can hold 10 objects of type `Student`: `Student a[10];`
2. An array that can hold 10 pointers of objects of type `Student`:
   `Student *a[10];`
3. An STL vector c that can hold 10 objects of type `Student`:
   `vector<Student> c;`
4. An STL vector that can hold 10 pointers of objects of type
   `Student`: `vector<Student*> d`

Which of the 4 (can be more than one) can be declared without creating any student objects?

My original thought was that all of them (a,b,c,d) but i was told that only the ones with pointers (b and d) could be declared without creating objects. I was hoping for some clarification on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

2,3,4.
(1) Already creates 10 students on declaration.
(2) Is array of pointers so no need in Student object just need in declaration of Student token (you can just have "class Student" empty declaration for it to work).
(3) until you don't put something inside std vector is empty. But in this case you need to have Student defined in the scope (like "class Student {};"), so restrictions are more strict than for 2.
(4) The same as 2.

Comment: I don't think 3 requires a default constructor.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. But you need Student to be not declared but defined in order for template to be created anyway.

Comment: Yes, you definitely need a complete type to instantiate a vector.

Answer (score 2):

In 2,4, the type you use is `Student *`, which is just a number pointing to an address like `0xff0f0f`. The object will not be created in this case, as you are creating an *address*, which can point to anything, or even nothing. So, you have to point them to actual objects later yourself. Think of them as defining something like `int address_array[10]`.

Also, 1 is different from 3. When you create an array like `Student a[10]`, you create 10 Student objects in memory, and calling the default constructors for each of them. In 3, when you define `vector<Student> a`, nothing really happens, until when you actually call something like `a.push_back(some_student)`.